# How can I quick fix an error from an C++ lib

Tags: c++

I'm a newbie on C++, and now I'm debugging an C# application that call an C++ library, then I got an error from C++ lib, I'm confused and don't know how to resolve the error, can anyone help to explain the C++ code by java or c# style?
I had found the code:

```
 bool ValidateClientClass(long clientClass)
      {
        if (clientClass > -1 && clientClass <= std::numeric_limits<FC::DataRecordBase::DataSource_t>::max())
          return true;
        return false;
      }
```

the input a client class '1', the I got false. I can't understand `std::numeric_limits<FC::DataRecordBase::DataSource_t>::max()`, how does this mean in C++?

I expect a method to return true from previous code.

Comment: It seems `FC::DataRecordBase::DataSource_t` is something in your source code. You need to know what the primitive type it is. Probably it's an `unsigned` type and it's compared with a `signed` type. Post `FC::DataRecordBase` if needed.

Comment: also possible is that you are not calling the function correctly from c#, can you show the pinvoke declaration and the calling code

Comment: It means `clientClass` is either negative or above some constant bound that was set by the person who wrote this C++ code. Either `DataSource_t` is a typedef somewhere that literally evaluates to `int` or some other primitive, or there's a custom specialization of `std::numeric_limits` somewhere in the client's code for that type (I don't think the latter is entirely kosher according to the standard, but I've seen people attempt it)